# What does this text mean at the end of .exe file?

Tags: exe, .net-assembly

I've seen this text at the end of a lot of .exe files. Can it tell me what language the .exe file was written in? I think it might be a .NET language because of the Microsoft references.

```
<!-- Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation -->
<!--
  Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

   Authors:
       GaryY

   Module name:
       wextract.manifest

   Abstract:
       Manifest to support IExpress WExtract.exe.
-->

  <assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
  <assemblyIdentity
    version="1.0.0.0"
    processorArchitecture="x86"
    name="wextract"
    type="win32"
  />

  <description>IExpress extraction tool</description>

  <dependency>
    <dependentAssembly>
       <assemblyIdentity
           type="win32"
           name="Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls"
           version="6.0.0.0"
           processorArchitecture="x86"
           publicKeyToken="6595b64144ccf1df"
           language="*"
       />
    </dependentAssembly>
  </dependency>

  <!-- Identify the application security requirements. -->

  <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
    <security>
      <requestedPrivileges>
        <requestedExecutionLevel
          level="asInvoker"
          uiAccess="false"/>
        </requestedPrivileges>
       </security>
  </trustInfo>

</assembly>
```

The rest of the file is just nonsense, except for this part. I opened the file in Notepad ++.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the *manifest* for the program.  It is embedded as a resource, similar to an icon.  It contains configuration info that Windows pays attention to.

The dependency element for  Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls tells Windows that it wants the XP version of visual style theming for its controls, not the legacy Windows 2000 look-and-feel.

The requestedPrivileges element declares the program compatible with UAC and doesn't need to be lied to when it does something *verboten* for a non-elevated program like writing to the c:\windows directory or the HKLM registry keys.

A manifest can contain additional entries for DLLs that are stored in the side-by-side cache (c:\windows\winsxs).  And are used to implement reg-free COM registration.  These kind of entries are DLL Hell countermeasures.

Any modern app written to run on Vista and up and has a GUI contains these manifest entries.  .NET programs have them too.  You can add a custom manifest with the Application Manifest File item template.  If you don't then you'll get a default manifest with just the UAC entry.

There is no hint what language was used to write the program.  The manifest is independent from the programming language.  Microsoft usually writes in C++.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's part of the self-extraction software MS uses for deploying EXEs. See [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IExpress) . VB.net and C# (and a few others) all get converted to an intermediate language called CIL before they're compiled, so I'd be surprised if you could learn the exact language from this xml documentation.